# OpenStack Autopilot issue

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have an Ubuntu server with 2 NIC cards on which I have installed a MAAS server. And I have three machines with 2 NIC card and 2 HDD each. Using virtual machine I have created 3 Nodes. So totally I have 6 nodes plus one server machine.

Everything is fine up to this point, I have installed the Landscape successfully. While logging in to the Landscape dash board I am getting the following error.

---

> At least three machine with more than one hard disk has been
>   commissioned.

---

Even though I have three machine with multiple hard disks , I am not able to configure the Landscape to auto pilot mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VIRTIO in the VMs for the disks, change that do SATA or something else. VIRTIO disks are not seen by "lshw", which is the tool MAAS uses to gather storage information.

Comment: I am using 3 VMs and 3 Physical machines. All three physical machines have 2 HDD each. Again i need to think about all VMs ?

Comment: If you already have at least 3 physical ones with two disks, then the issue is still probably the same: the second disk isn't being seen. Go to the respective MAAS nodes and inspect the hardware that was detected. You may need to inspect the commissioning output, and/or lshw xml output details.

Comment: Yes I have checked all three machines in MAAS. the lshw xml shows all two hdd in all three physical machines.

Comment: Are these iSCSI "disks" by any chance? The installer will ignore those as well (for now).

Comment: every disk is identified as IDE only. For your reference i attached the xml of all three machines.                                                                    Machine 1 :-   http://paste.ubuntu.com/13006833/                        Machine 2 :-  http://paste.ubuntu.com/13006835/                      Machine 3 :-  http://paste.ubuntu.com/13006836/